# ¿Cómo hallar el elemento más repetido en una lista en Python?

Tags: python, lista, elementos

Tengo una lista a la que podemos llamar a que está llena de elementos, y me gustaría saber cuántas veces se repite cada elemento y cuál es el más y menos repetido, ¿cómo podría hacer?

En el hipotético caso de que el más repetido sea 2 veces y pase con 2 número como podría indicarlo. Por ejemplo a= [1,1,2,2,3]. En esta lista hay 2 elementos que se repiten dos veces, ¿cómo lo puedo indicar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la libreria de Pandas, ella realizara todo el proceso con un par de lineas.

Supongamos que tenemos la lista que nos indicas:

```
[1,1,2,2,3]
```

Nuestro código, seria el siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd                   # Importas la libreria pandas y accedes a ella con el identificador pd

lista = pd.Series([1,2,1,5])          # Creas la lista, con los datos que sean necesarios 

resultados = lista.value_counts()     # Creas una variable (opcional) que contiene  los resultados que necesitas

print(resultados)
```

Resultados consta de dos columnas. La primera [1,2,5] contiene todos los valores que se han encontrado en la lista. La segunda contiene cuantas veces se repite cada valor:

```
print(resultados)

1    2
2    1
5    1
```

El mismo ejercicio con letras.

```
import pandas as pd

lista = pd.Series(['a','b','a', 'o', 'o', 'u'])
resultados = lista.value_counts()

print(resultados)

o    2
a    2
u    1
b    1
```

Answer (score 3):

Python cuenta con una clase llamada [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects) dentro de `collections` que te permite contar las repeticiones dentro de un iterable, así como ofrecerte información relevante sobre ellos.

```py
from collections import Counter

a = [1,1,2,2,3]
counter = Counter(a)

first, second, *_, last = counter.most_common()

print(first, second, last)
```

### Explicacion del programa

1. La primera parte del programa simplemente crea una instancia de la clase `Counter` que toma como argumento un iterable, en este caso la variable `a`.

```py
a = [1,1,2,2,3]
counter = Counter(a)
```

2. En una segunda parte, y considerando que solo quieres saber los dos elementos con mayor repetición, así como el elemento con menor cantidad de repeticiones, es que hacemos uso de [unpacking](https://stackabuse.com/unpacking-in-python-beyond-parallel-assignment/#:%7E:text=Unpacking%20in%20Python%20refers%20to,the%20iterable%20unpacking%20operator%2C%20*%20.) para obtener únicamente estos elementos. El método `most_common()` sin argumentos, retorna los elementos ordenados en forma ascendente con respecto al número de repeticiones que tiene cada uno. De manera más estricta, cada elemento es definido como un tupla de dos valores, en donde el primer índice contiene el elemento como tal (1, 2 o 3 en este caso) y el segundo índice contiene el número de repeticiones.

```py
first, second, *_, last = counter.most_common()
```

Si no te sientes muy comodo con unpacking, puedes traducirlo a:

```py
elementos_ordenados = counter.most_common()
first = elementos_ordenados[0]
second = elementos_ordenados[1]
// Ignora todos los valores intermedios
last = elementos_ordenados[-1]
```

Al final del programa, el print debe imprimir algo similar a:

```py
(1, 2) (2, 2) (3, 1)
```

Donde, como comentaba anteriormente, el primer valor de cada tupla es el elemento y el segundo valor es el número de repeticiones.

> **Nota.** Es importante tomar en cuenta que el unpacking esta tomando como premisa que al menos existen 3 elementos distintos para asignar a las variables(first, second, last), en caso contrario va arrojar un error.

Answer (score 2):

El problema tiene dos partes:

1. Contar cuántas veces se repite cada elemento. Puedes crear un diccionario en el que cada clave sea cada posible dato, y los valores sean el número de veces que se ha repetido cada uno. Esto te lo hace `itertools.Counter()` aunque no es muy difícil implementar tú mismo una versión de lo que hace `Counter()`, si prefieres no usar módulos (aunque es un módulo de la biblioteca estándar)
2. Encontrar el más repetido y el menos repetido. Esto también te lo hace `Counter()` si quieres. El detalle aquí es, como tú mismo preguntas, qué hacer si hay "empate" entre dos datos que tienen igual número de repeticiones y ambos están en el máximo.

Creo que una solución sencilla podría ser, una vez resuelto (1), crear un diccionario inverso en el que cada clave sea el número de repeticiones y cada valor sea una lista con los datos que han presentado ese número de repeticiones.

Hagámoslo tomando como ejemplo los datos de partida que propones.

```
a= [1,1,2,2,3]

# 1 . Hacer un diccionario en el que las claves sean los datos
#     y los valores el número de repeticiones

# Para esto puedes usar itertools.Counter() o implementarlo tú mismo
# veamos por ejemplo una implementación

def contar(datos):
  result = {}
  for dato in datos:
    if dato not in result:
      result[dato] = 0    # Meter contador 0
    result[dato] += 1      # Incrementar el contador de ese dato
  return result 

cuenta = contar(a)
```

El resultado es el diccionario:

```
{1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1}
```

Que se leería así: "El 1 aparece 2 veces, el 2 aparece 2 veces, el 3 aparece 1 vez"

Pasemos a la segunda fase:

```
# 2. Crear diccionario inverso, las claves son el número de repeticiones
#    y los valores son listas con los datos que se han repetido ese número
#    de veces

dic_inverso = {}
for dato, repeticiones in cuenta.items():
  if repeticiones not in dic_inverso:
    dic_inverso[repeticiones] = []     # Inicializar con lista vacía
  dic_inverso[repeticiones].append(dato) # Añadir dato a la lista
```

Al ejecutar este código al final `dic_inverso` contendrá:

```
{1: [3], 2: [1, 2]}
```

que se leería así: "Elementos con 1 repeticion: el 3. Elementos con 2 repeticiones: el 1 y el 2"

Ahora ya es sencillo responder qué elemento (o elementos) son el más repetido y el menos repetido:

```
max_rep = max(dic_inverso)
min_rep = min(dic_inverso)

print(f"El máximo de repeticiones es {max_rep} y corresponde a {dic_inverso[max_rep]}")
print(f"El mínimo de repeticiones es {min_rep} y corresponde a {dic_inverso[min_rep]}")
```

Al ejecutar esto en pantalla se mostrará:

```
El máximo de repeticiones es 2 y corresponde a [1, 2]
El mínimo de repeticiones es 1 y corresponde a [3]
```